# Rails 4 Devise and STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I read the two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278537/devise-with-single-table-inheritance-sti) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472852/devise-and-multiple-user-models), but still have trouble figuring out how everything is tied together.  Basically I have 2 types of users, Trainers and Clients.  They share some common attributes (email, phone, first name, last name, etc), but they will also have some custom attributes.

Assuming STI is the way to go, I would have 3 models:

- User (devise)
- Trainer (inherits from User)
- Client (inherits from User)

When the user signs up, they should be able to use the same form and just select from a drop down if they're a trainer or client.  Once the form is submitted how do I go about specifying the type of user that has just been created?  Do I need logic in the controller to check the user type, and then run `Trainer.create()` or `Client.create()`?

Comment: Yes, put this into the controller.

Comment: Any idea why i would be getting "Invalid single-table inheritance type: trainer is not a subclass of User"?

Comment: `trainer` != `Trainer`. Ensure that you have the correct value in the `type` column.

Comment: Doh! Was banging my head on keyboard for hours and that was the issue.  Thanks